# Validation List of Cell with filtered values of Table Header

Tags: excel, vba

I want to put to Data validation for a column based on Headers of a named table.
Users will add more columns with country name as headers.
I have tried giving data validation the cell to named range, Named range value is `=TripCost[#Headers] 'TripCost is the the name of the table`.
But I am getting all the values. I want to ignore whichever value start with "Remark" or "Cost".
Is there a way to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: When you say "Cost" do you mean a header containing the "Cost" string inside? I mean "Cost Break-up/Trip(Plan)" should be excluded? "Remark3" should also be excluded from the list? I mean, do you need only the countries enumeration?

Comment: Yes, I need only country list.. I need only the country list. Users will add columns with country name as header.

Comment: Then, try the code I posted, please. It should do what (I understood) you need. Please, confirm that it does what you want.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you.. Its exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. It will create a validation for the active cell, using as many countries your named range will contain:

```
Private Sub selectiveNameValidation()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, arrH As Variant, El As Variant, strList As String

 Set sh = ActiveSheet

  Set rng = ActiveCell 'use here what range you need
  
  'arrH = Range("Headers").Value 'use here a named range for the headers in discussion ("Headers")
  'or use your Table headers:
  arrH = sh.ListObjects("TripCost").HeaderRowRange.Value' load the range in an array
  For Each El In arrH
    If Not (InStr(El, "Cost") > 0 Or InStr(El, "Remark") > 0) Then
         strList = strList & IIf(strList = "", "", ",") & El 'build the list string
    End If
  Next

  With rng.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                                                xlBetween, Formula1:=strList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
  End With
End Sub
```

If other strings to be excluded will appear, you must only extend the line

```
If Not (InStr(El, "Cost") > 0 Or InStr(El, "Remark") > 0) Then
```

with the new one:

```
If Not (InStr(El, "Cost") > 0 Or InStr(El, "Remark") > 0 Or InStr(El, "NewOne") > 0 ) Then
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim objList As ListObject
    Dim vR(), vDB
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    
    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set objList = Ws.ListObjects("TripCost")
    
    vDB = objList.HeaderRowRange
    For j = 2 To UBound(vDB, 2) Step 2
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
        vR(n) = vDB(1, j)
    Next j
    sFormula = Join(vR, ",")
    
    Set Target = ActiveCell
    
    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, sFormula
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```